# Help me understand linear separability in a binary SVM

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm cross-posting this from [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/help-me-understand-linearly-separability-in-a-binary-svm) because I'm not getting any feedback and it's a time-sensitive question for me.

---

My question pertains to linear separability with hyperplanes in a support vector machine.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machineclassifier.):

> ...formally, a support vector machine
>   constructs a hyperplane or set of
>   hyperplanes in a high or infinite
>   dimensional space, which can be used
>   for classification, regression or
>   other tasks. Intuitively, a good
>   separation is achieved by the
>   hyperplane that has the largest
>   distance to the nearest training data
>   points of any class (so-called
>   functional margin), since in general
>   the larger the margin the lower the
>   generalization error of the
>   classifier.classifier.

The linear separation of classes by hyperplanes intuitively makes sense to me. And I think I understand linear separability for two-dimensional geometry. However, I'm implementing an SVM using a popular SVM library (libSVM) and when messing around with the numbers, I fail to understand how an SVM can create a curve between classes, or enclose central points in category 1 within a circular curve when surrounded by points in category 2 if a hyperplane in an n-dimensional space V is a "flat" subset of dimension n − 1, or for two-dimensional space - a 1D line.

### Here is what I mean:

[image: circularly enclosed class separation for a 2D binary SVM]

That's not a hyperplane. That's circular. How does this work? Or are there more dimensions inside the SVM than the two-dimensional 2D input features?

---

This example application can be downloaded [here](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html).

---

### **Edit:**

Thanks for your comprehensive answers. So the SVM can separate weird data well by using a kernel function. Would it help to linearize the data before sending it to the SVM? For example, one of my input features (a numeric value) has a turning point (eg. 0) where it neatly fits into category 1, but above and below zero it fits into category 2. Now, because I know this, would it help classification to send the absolute value of this feature for the SVM?

Comment: Linearizing the data is an option, but one of the nice things about a kernel function is that you don't actually need to construct such a space.  The kernel is effectively a measure of dis-similarity of the data points.  Actually finding a space that realizes some arbitrary inner product may involve introducing an infinite number of dimensions.  But all the SVM algorithm needs is an inner product.  In fact, IIRC, all it really needs is something sufficiently "like" an inner product.

Comment: This question is on-topic here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shane: Yeah, but SO's bigger audience gets quicker answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mokus explained, support vector machines use a *kernel function* to implicitly map data into a feature space where they are linearly separable:

[image: SVM mapping one feature space into another]

Different kernel functions are used for various kinds of data. Note that an extra dimension (feature) is added by the transformation in the picture, although this feature is never materialized in memory.

(Illustration from [Chris Thornton, U. Sussex](http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/courses/dm/lec10.html).)

Comment: How does the SVM know which kernel function will separate the data sensibly? Does it iterate though a bunch of equations and calculate which produces the largest margin? See also edits to my question.

Comment: The kernel is typically set by the user/developer as a parameter. LibSVM, for instance, has linear, polynomial, RBF and sigmoid kernel types. Its authors recommend the RBF kernel for beginners.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA) that illustrates an example of linearly inseparable points that become separable by a plane when mapped to a higher dimension.

[image]

Comment: great video I wish I could find more things like this!

Answer (score 3):

I am not intimately familiar with SVMs, but from what I recall from my studies they are often used with a "kernel function" - essentially, a replacement for the standard inner product that effectively non-linearizes the space.  It's loosely equivalent to applying a nonlinear transformation from your space into some "working space" where the linear classifier is applied, and then pulling the results back into your original space, where the linear subspaces the classifier works with are no longer linear.

The wikipedia article does mention this in the subsection "Non-linear classification", with a link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick which explains the technique more generally.

Comment: As I recall, Numerical Recipes had a pretty good section on implementing SVMs with kernel functions to solve nonlinear classification problems.

Comment: Actually, the "pulling the results back" step is never needed, even if you'd do the feature space expansion manually. You'd just do dot products in the expanded feature space, giving a single number per SV/test sample pair.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by applying what is know as a [Kernel Trick] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick)
What basically is done is that if something is not linearly separable in the existing input space ( 2-D in your case), it is projected to a higher dimension where this would be separable. A kernel function ( can be non-linear) is applied to modify your feature space. All computations are then performed in this feature space (which can be possibly of infinite dimensions too).

Each point in your input is transformed using this kernel function, and all further computations are performed as if this was your original input space. Thus, your points may be separable in a higher dimension (possibly infinite) and thus the linear hyperplane in higher dimensions might not be linear in the original dimensions.

For a simple example, consider the example of XOR. If you plot Input1 on X-Axis, and Input2 on Y-Axis, then the output classes will be:

1. Class 0: (0,0), (1,1)
2. Class 1: (0,1), (1,0)

As you can observe, its not linearly seperable in 2-D. But if I take these ordered pairs in 3-D, (by just moving 1 point in 3-D) say:

1. Class 0: (0,0,1), (1,1,0)
2. Class 1: (0,1,0), (1,0,0)

Now you can easily observe that there is a plane in 3-D to separate these two classes linearly.

Thus if you project your inputs to a sufficiently large dimension (possibly infinite), then you'll be able to separate your classes linearly in that dimension.

One important point to notice here (and maybe I'll answer your other question too) is that you don't have to make a kernel function yourself (like I made one above). The good thing is that the kernel function automatically takes care of your input and figures out how to "linearize" it.

Answer (score 1):

For the SVM example in the question given in 2-D space let x1, x2 be the two axes. You can have a transformation function F = x1^2 + x2^2 and transform this problem into a 1-D space problem. If you notice carefully you could see that in the transformed space, you can easily linearly separate the points(thresholds on F axis). Here the transformed space was [ F ] ( 1 dimensional ) . In most cases , you would be increasing the dimensionality to get linearly separable hyperplanes.

Comment: This is my interpretation as well, since the linearity in terms of the output from the kernel and not on the shape of the kernel itself. If there were four dimensions F=x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^3 + x4^2, it is still 1 dimensional on a threshold of values of F.

Answer (score 0):

[SVM clustering](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/8/S7/S18)

[image: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/8/S7/S18/figure/F4]

HTH

Answer (score 0):

[My answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148513/difference-between-a-linear-problem-and-a-non-linear-problem-essence-of-dot-prod/1149561#1149561) might shed some light on what is happening in this case. The example I give is very contrived and not really what happens in an SVM, but it should give you come intuition.